# I updated python to 3.7 from 3.5 and now manage.py cannot be found

Tags: python, django, pycharm

```
(venv) C:\Users\...\PycharmProjects\WebP1>python manage.py runserver
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe: can't open file 'manage.py': 
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

This is the error I get post updating to Python. Just before i updated the command was working and I could run my website.

Should I revert back to 3.5 or how can I actually get my py file to be found?

Comment: It looks like you're using a virtualenv. Try re-creating the venv from scratch using Python 3.7.

Comment: Will that get rid of my whole venv?

Comment: Yes, that's the point. You can create the new venv in a new folder next to the old one. Use `pip freeze > requirements.txt` and `pip install -r requirements.txt` to save the list of installed packages in the old venv and restore it in the new. Or take this opportunity to switch to Pipenv, which handles this stuff a lot better.

Comment: @Thomas i fixed it. The update just moved me out a directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to be another directory deep when doing the command after the update took place. For some reason the update moved me out a directory.

```
cd [folder name]
(venv) C:\Users\...\PycharmProjects\WebP1\[folder name]>python manage.py runserver
```